# make table in hive with only Y and N value (create external table or insert overwrite)

Tags: oracle, hive, hiveql

(Looking for every possibilities to create with `external table` or `insert overwrite table`).

So I have to make dual-table like in oracle in hive.
It will use as joined table with query like this:

```
  ...
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT 'Y' flag FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 'N' flag FROM dual
  )rwrw
WHERE 1=1
...
```

What is the best way to do this, when the data is stored in "/user/hive/warehouse/temp.db/" ?

Thank you

Comment: The usage scenario is not clear. You can use stack() to generate table on the fly, also you do not need dual to select literals or functions in Hive.

Comment: Im not clear about what are you going to tell me..

Comment: answered, please check

Answer (score 0):

Hive do not have `dual` table like oracle but best way to achieve it is as follows:

```
  ...
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT 'Y' as flag
  UNION
  SELECT 'N' as flag
  )rwrw
WHERE 1=1
...
```

Comment: yeah, i know. I am asking for the possibilities (create external table or inset overwrite table)

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is using stack, it will generate table which you can use in query, it will not read hdfs, it is in-memory table:

```
with temp_table as (
select stack(2, --the number of tuples
             'Y', 
             'N'
            ) as flag
)

select
...
  LEFT OUTER JOIN temp_table
...
```

See one more example of using stack: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57363924/2700344

Example with many columns: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55157055/2700344